# Removing Shower Door Track

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathtub, adhesive, bathroom-fixtures

I am a relatively new home owner with much to learn. I successfully removed an ugly and basically non-functional shower door, but the bottom track is seemingly welded to the bathtub. I assume there’s a really strong bonding compound that was used. I tried using a hair dryer to loosen the compound but had no luck. Does anyone have any ideas on how to remove this piece or am I doomed until I install an entirely new tub? A few photos of the track are attached. Many thanks for your help and suggestions.

[image: Shower Door Track 1]

[image: Shower Door Track 2]

Comment: A few photos added!

Comment: You're looking at a pretty large heat sink; I suspect it's going to be hard for a hot air gun to warm it enough to make much difference.... I'd be tempted to just leave it in place and just put some sort of trim over the top to guard users against the edge. (Split tubing, grooved plastic or water-resistant wood, etc.)

Comment: Fascinating idea! Thank you.

Comment: Once you the track off, I would encourage you to come back and let us know how it went, for the next person searching for a similar project.

Answer (score 2):

Unless whomever installed it was a sadist and used construction adhesive or something more permanent, they likely used a silicone adhesive or caulking; probably the same caulking that was used to seal the tub at the time of installation.

A thin putty knife should be able to be worked under the end of the track. Or even a butter knife from the kitchen, if you have limited tools. You will want to be careful to avoid scratching the tub, so consider trying a plastic one first.

If you can get under the end of the track, you might be able to get a thin piece of wire, nylon string, or even dental floss under that end. Then hold one end of the floss in each hand and try pulling it while working it back and forth with a sawing motion.

You will either see results quickly or it won't work at all...

Comment: Ha ha ha, I mean the sadist angle is certainly possible. It’s really, really adhered.  I will try all of your possible solutions! Many thanks for the great ideas.

Comment: Braided fishing line is particularly good (you'll want handles on the ends of it.)

Answer (score 0):

I like the wire suggestion from @spuck but here is an act of desperation.  I hope you can ignore it:

Saw slits in the track every two inches across the entire width and as far through the track as you dare without scratching the tub.  This will allow your removal force to act locally and with more twisting.  Two inches at a time.  I think the stiffness of the track results in your trying to pull most of it off all at once.  Experiment, if it works try 4 inches etc.

Comment: Also a great idea!